# How to write to page in java script DOm model

Tags: javascript

I am doing a java script application that calculates Miles driven / gallons used and gallons used* price per gallon. I have two problems:

1) when I enter all the values price per gallon adds a another zero automatically. For example 40, becomes 400.
2) I am looking to write the result of both calculations underneath the button.
 If anyone can give me guidance or help I would really appreciate it.

```
 <!DOCTYPE 
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title> MPG application </title>

    <script>
    var $ = function(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);

    }
    /* the user entries will be parsed  floats and a if 
    statment is checking to see if the person enters not  #*/
    var calculateMpg = function () {
        var miles = parseFloat($("miles").value); //alert(miles);
        var gallons = parseFloat($("gallons").value);
                 var costGallon = document.getElementById("costGallon").value;

        if (isNaN(miles) || isNaN(gallons)) {
            alert("enter a valid number");    

        }

        else {
         var mpg = miles/gallons;

        var costGallon = gallons*costGallon;
    $("costGallon").value=costGallon.toFixed(2);    
    //alert("your total is" +mpg );
    alert("your total  new is " + costGallon);
    //cost of trip  = gallons used * price per gallon


        }


    }
    //write to the page
    window.onload = function () {
        $("calculate").onclick = calculateMpg;
        //focues means brings the window to the front
        $("costGallon").focus();

    }

    </script>
    </head>
    <section>
    <body>
    <h1> calculate mPG </h1>
    <p>Enter the information below</p>

    <label for="miles">Miles Driven: </label>
    <!--the code under gives a form box of text-->
    <input type="text" id="miles"> <br><br>&nbsp;
    <label for = "gallons"> Gallons of gas used :</label>
    <input = "text" id="gallons"><br><br>&nbsp;
    <label for = "costGallon"> Price per Gallon: </label>
    <input = "text" id="costGallon" ><br><br>
    <label>&nbsp;</label>
    <input type = "button" id = "calculate" value = "Calculate MPG and cost of the trip">
    <!-- So here I want to say your mpg is and then call mpg. which I thought I did in the top  abobe window.onload -->
        <p style="color: red"> Your mpg is: <span id = "totalMpg"> </span>
    </section>


    </body>


    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you give me an example of where it does that? I copy pasted your code and for me it gives the correct values. From what I understand the only thing you are writting into the cost per gallon field is the gallons used times the price per gallon. An that seems to be working fine.

If you can provide me with a example calculation you want to achive i'd be happy to help.

On another note, i suggest not using the same variable again in line 27 that you used to hold the DOM object of the input field. Also toFixed does not change the variable you used it on but return a new variable so instead remove that in line 28 and have line 27 look something like this:

var newVarNameIsBoss = (gallons*costGallon).toFixed(2);

Hope this helps

revised code

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <!-- scorrect doctype-->
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title> MPG application </title>

<script>
var $ = function(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
};//remember that a var decleration always ends with a ; even if it's a function

/* the user entries will be parsed  floats and a if 
statment is checking to see if the person enters not  #*/
var calculateMpg = function () {
    var miles = parseFloat($("miles").value), //alert(miles);
    gallons = parseFloat($("gallons").value),
    costGallon = document.getElementById("costGallon").value,
    mpg,totalCost;

    if (isNaN(miles) || isNaN(gallons)) {
        alert("enter a valid number");    

    } else {
        mpg = miles/gallons;
        totalCost = (gallons*costGallon).toFixed(2);
        costGallon.value=totalCost;  
        alert("your total  new is " + totalCost);
        $('totalMpg').innerHTML = String(mpg.toFixed(2)) + " Miles per Gallon";
    }


};//remember that a var decleration always ends with a ; even if it's a function

//write to the page
window.onload = function () {
    $("calculate").onclick = calculateMpg;
    //focues means brings the window to the front
    $("costGallon").focus();

};//remember that a var decleration always ends with a ; even if it's a function

</script>
</head>

<body>
<section> <!-- section bellow the body tag-->
<h1> calculate mPG </h1>
<p>Enter the information below</p>

<label for="miles">Miles Driven: </label>
<!--the code under gives a form box of text-->
<input type="text" id="miles"> <br/><br/>&nbsp;
<label for = "gallons"> Gallons of gas used :</label>
<input = "text" id="gallons"><br/><br/>&nbsp;
<label for = "costGallon"> Price per Gallon: </label>
<input = "text" id="costGallon" ><br/><br/>
<label>&nbsp;</label>
<input type = "button" id = "calculate" value = "Calculate MPG and cost of the trip">
<!-- So here I want to say your mpg is and then call mpg. which I thought I did in the top  abobe window.onload -->
    <p style="color: red"> Your mpg is: <span id = "totalMpg"> </span></p><!--closing p tag here-->
</section>


</body>


</html>
```

Comment: Hi, so when I enter 10 for gallons of gas used and then 40 for price per gallon and then I press calculate MPG and cost of the trip button it adds 400.0 in the 450.0 price field. You are not getting that issue?

Comment: Hi, just to be sure you are interested in calculating Miles per gallon and total cost of the trip. So you do two calculations:

Miles/Gallons Used = MPG   and  Gallons Used * Price per gallon = Total Price. The total price is currently displayed in the alert and the MPG in the red text.

For this example 230 Miles, 9 Gallons, price per gallon 7.5$ the total costs is 9*7.5 = 67.5$ Total Cost and 230/9 = 25.56 MPG

This is exaclty the result that my code will give you. If you want to calculate somethign else please let me know. Could it be that you are using a "," for floats instead of a "." ???

Comment: just copy paste my code into a new file and try it out ;)